# Pull private registry image with kubernetes-helm app without using imagepullsecret

Tags: docker, kubernetes-helm, minikube, docker-registry, azure-cli

I am using minikube to develop my Kubernetes application. I have a private azure registry where my images are saved. Whenever I start the app, k8s start to pull an image. It throws the following error

```
Failed to pull image "myregistry.azurecr.io/myapp:mytag": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://myregistry.azurecr.io/v2/myapp/manifests/mytag: unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.
```

I am configuring my minikube using [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#configuring-nodes-to-authenticate-to-a-private-registry) documentation. where first, I log-in to acr using below command,

```
az acr login --name myregistry.azurecr.io --expose-token
```

And after using the token provided by the above command, I log-in to my private docker-registry by the below command in minikube ssh.

```
docker login myregistry.azurecr.io -u 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

After that as per mention in the document, I copy the .docker/config.json to /var/lib/kubelet/config.json in minikube ssh. Still I am facing above error.

If I manually pull the image using the docker pull command, it works. I tried with imagepullsecret also and it is working. But from the above method, getting an authentication error. Do I have missing any step here? Can you please help me?

Thanks...

Comment: Any more updates on the question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems all the steps are right. Maybe you can check if you really copy the config file to all the minikube nodes. In default, the command `minikube ssh` connect the control plane. You can check if the nodes' IP addresses is right when you copy the config file to them.

But in my opinion, it's not a good way to use the way like this. It's better and more convenient to use the imagePullSecret and service account.

Comment: Thanks, Charles Xu for your quick response. Sorry I was on holiday. You are right it's a better way to use imagePullSecret. But I found the way today that we can use the plugin of minikube (registry-creds). We can set our clientid & password for the registry there. Then Kubernetes use these credentials to pull the image. No need to provide imagePullSecret.

Comment: @aryan What do you mean by clientid & password? The service principal ID and password?

Comment: @Charls Xu, Yes. While setting credentials it asks for,
-- Enter client ID (service principal ID) to access ACR: XXXXX
For more information check the following URL,
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/registry/

Comment: @aryan The service principal client id and the password can be also used in the imagepullsecret.